# Team Foundation Server project portal (reporting services) user access rights

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I'm having trouble figuring out how to setup user access rights for project portals in TFS 2010.

> The permissions granted to user XXXXXXX are insufficient for performing this operation (rsAccessDenied)

[image]

I've tried adding the user to the various admin groups in TFS but the problem seems to *only* be related to Reporting Services permissions.

I mapped this user to the RSExec role in the RS databases as well as made sure they had access to the IIS virtual directory.   I've tried several of the solutions found through Google but many of them are for previous versions of TFS/RS and the options don't even apply, others don't seem to work at all.

Ideally I would like to add an entire domain group to the entire project collection so that they can access any project portal underneath it, I don't want to have to setup custom permissions on each project, let alone various web parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this tool: http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/ to administer TFS/SharePoint/SSRS in a consolidated interface.

Comment: I saw a link to that tool in an older post and it said it was completely unstable, looks like it's been updated since then and works quite well now.  Doesn't allow you to admin at the collection level but that's ok.  Thanks.

Comment: No you can't administer at the TPC collection, but the Team Project level is fine and yes it's working pretty well now. The tool is far from perfect, but it's the best we've got so far (and it amazes me that 7 years after the debut of TFS we still poor unsupported tooling for administration)